# 「ksproxy.ax のシンボルが読み込まれていません」というエラーについて

Tags: windows, visual-studio

部分的に実行できるようになりました。
そこで実行してみたところ、次のエラーが出てきました。

「ksproxy.ax のシンボルが読み込まれていません」

検索してみたら、次のサイトが見つかりました。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc354739.aspx
どうやら、DirectShow は KsProxy フィルタ (ksproxy.ax) を提供しているのだが、それが読み込まれていないらしい。

これにはどう対処したらよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 過去の質問について質問したまま放置せず、（質問者さんの抱える問題ではなく）質問文に記載した内容が解決したのであれば、[回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)実行してください。問題が解決していないのであれば、質問文を補足し何を求めているのかを明確にしてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そもそもエラーではありません。そもそもの問題として`ksproxy.ax`もしくはそれに関連したデバッグを行いたいのでしょうか？

[シンボル (.pdb) ファイル、ソース ファイル、およびバイナリ ファイルの検索](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger)で説明されていますが、`Microsoft シンボル サーバー`にチェックを付けると、Microsoft シンボル サーバーからダウンロード、読み込みが行われるようになります。その場合、メッセージが「シンボルが読み込まれました。」に切り替わるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。早速試してみます。